# Hyperlink on Gridview from Sql Database

Tags: gridview, hyperlink

I have a gridview on my webpage and its source is an sql database.  one of the columns in the Database are website addresses for companies.  The column is named "Attachments".  I am trying to set up a hyperlink in the gridview that when selected will launch that companies website (every row in the database has a different website in this column.  Everywhere I look I only find how to set up a static url for the hyperlinks and no way of launching the URL that is in the column.  Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong so that I can have each hyperlink a unique webpage link.

Also, my gridview is embedded in an Iframe on the webpage.  Is there a way I can get the hyperlink to NOT launch within the Iframe but to launch as a completely separate page.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" GridLines="Vertical">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#DCDCDC" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Group_Name" HeaderText="Group" SortExpression="Group_Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" SortExpression="Address" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" SortExpression="City" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="First_Phone_Number" HeaderText="1st Number" SortExpression="First_Phone_Number" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Second_Phone_Number" HeaderText="2nd Number" SortExpression="Second_Phone_Number" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Fax_Phone_Number" HeaderText="Fax Number" SortExpression="Fax_Phone_Number" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Notes" HeaderText="Notes" SortExpression="Notes" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Attachments" ItemStyle-Width="30">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Attachments", "~/HtmlAttachmentPage.html?Id+{0}") %>'
                        Text='<%# Eval("Attachments") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
```